# How to assign c# WPF output to TV screen while another program may be running on the laptop

Tags: c#, wpf, screen, television

I am trying to play a video with c# wpf to tv screen from mylaptop.
On the laptop another program may be running.
How can I direct the screen output of wpf to tv screen
while having another program playing something on the laptop's screen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the TV is your second screen, you can try show your wpf window on second screen:

```
var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
if (Screen.AllScreens.Length > 1)
{
   Screen s = Screen.AllScreens[1];
   Rectangle r = s.WorkingArea;
   mainWindow.Top = r.Top;
   mainWindow.Left = r.Left;
   mainWindow.Show();
}
```